# Exception while deleting section from UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I am populating a tableview at runtime. I have set an edit option for it where I can delete sections from it. Number of sections depends on an array and there is only one row in a section.

Problem:

When I click the **Delete** button I receive an exception in log which says:

> Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-1448.89/UITableView.m:974

**commitEditingStyle:**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
       // [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:YES];

        Customer *objCustomer = [arrCustomerList objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
        NSString *strCusID = [objCustomer customerID];
        CustomerModel *objCustomerModel = [[CustomerModel alloc]init];
        [objCustomerModel deleteCustomer:strCusID];
       [tableView beginUpdates];
            [tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:indexPath.section] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];

        [tableView endUpdates];
        [tableView reloadData];

    }   
}
```

Comment: the number of sections returned by the data source can be wrong

Comment: you can log it just before the return statement, in `numberOfSections...`

Comment: I am debugging my application. Number of sections always comes correct.

Comment: Can you post the whole error message? It should say with more detail what went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try doing it by placing `beginUpdates` call at the beginning,

```
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
    [tableView beginUpdates];
    Customer *objCustomer = [arrCustomerList objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSString *strCusID = [objCustomer customerID];
    CustomerModel *objCustomerModel = [[CustomerModel alloc]init];
    [objCustomerModel deleteCustomer:strCusID];
    [tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:indexPath.section]
             withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
    [tableView endUpdates];
    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

because insert/delete/update opertions must be placed between `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates`.

Here's Apple doc :

> If you do not make the insertion, deletion, and selection calls inside
>   this block, table attributes such as row count might become invalid.

Also, if the concerned section is the last, make sure you still return 1 for the number of sections. In this case, still return 1 for number of sections and return 0 as the number of rows.

Comment: think you will have to check the way you delete the customer

Comment: I have check in my database after calling **deleteCustomer**. The record is successfully deleted. And I unable to find link to Apple doc you have mentioned.

Comment: this is just the doc for `UITableView`

Comment: is that the last section you try to delete ?

Comment: No, the problem comes on all the sections.

Comment: Thanks Vince for all your help. I found the solution to the problem. I have edited my question and added **Solved** section. Your point of Apple doc came out to be handy for me. But still I am not able to figure out the reason for the problem and what difference did my change make.

Comment: Offtopic: You dont have to call `[tableView reloadData];` when you want to keep the animation.

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately I found the solution to my problem. Following is the code I used to get rid of the problem:

```
Customer *objCustomer = [arrCustomerList objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
NSString *strCusID = [objCustomer customerID];
CustomerModel *objCustomerModel = [[CustomerModel alloc]init];
[objCustomerModel deleteCustomer:strCusID];
[arrCustomerList removeObject:objCustomer];
[tableView reloadData];
```